# Why my relation in Laravel are working backwards when I try to get an one to one associated value?

Tags: php, laravel

I got this error

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.product_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`product_id` = 2 and `categories`.`product_id` is not null limit 1) (View: /home/osboxes/shakira/resources/views/products/index.blade.php)
```

But my models and migrations are just fine. I have to erase migrations also from the database table and yes, I have my `category_id` in the `produc` table.

I'm trying to show the category in the index view.

Comment: you have defined your relationships incorrectly, most likely you set them up inverse ... the `hasOne` should be `belongsTo` and vise versa ... the table that has the key on it that points to another table "belongs to" the other table it points to

Comment: THANKS! But... not really sure about that :p

Answer (score 0):

Please share your information completely so people can understand and help you.

I guess you defined your relation backward in your models.
They should be like this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know how to use the code thing correctly u.u

Comment: Try to add functions to the proper model I wrote for you. `public function category()` must go to Product model and `public function products()` must go in Category.